# Creating a straight line motion path using the Maya API

Tags: maya, maya-api

I'm working on a project and for it I need to be able to create a straight line motion path and attach a camera to it. Once the camera moves along that path completely, I also need to render it from the camera's view, all with the Maya API.

Could anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: You need to be more specific with that you are asking.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you already tried something or are you looking for a tutorial?

Comment: Please post what you have tried and why it's not working.